# How can I transfer weight paint between different vertex groups of the same object?

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I'm very new to Blender, and I'm mainly learning how to model environments for historical recreations. I'm using BiomeReader to scatter vegetation in a project, and it requires a new vertex group to set the density of every different type of plant or scattered object with weight paint.

This means that I have a single mesh with several vertex groups. The problem is that I need all these vertex groups to have the exact same weight paint and I can't figure out how to do it other than manually painting every single group (and I will go insane if I have to do it like that), since all the other questions on a similar topic are about transfering vertex weight between different objects. I can provide screenshots if needed.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the weight constant, in these separate vertex groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may copy vertex weights using this menu:

[image]

it will create an exact copy of weights in a new vertex group

More advanced way is using **Weight Mix** modifier, that allows different methods to blend vertices and mix mask.

Set **Vertex Set** to "All" (tell Blender that you want to affect all vertices) and in "replace" **mix mode** weights will be transferred from B to A.

[image]

When you are ok with results, apply modifier.

Comment: Thank you! The Weight Mix modifier worked perfectly :)